# Binding a custom JavaScript control to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a set of pure JavaScript controls that are initiated like this:

```
var myControl = new SVGColorPicker("name", "#rrggbb");
myControl.insert("tagIdValue");
```

or, alternatively, in html:

```
<div><script>myControl.draw()</script></div>
```

The controls have getValue() and setValue(value) methods, and they harbor a hidden html input element so that the values appear in the form submits.

I am looking for some guidance how to bind these controls to the AngularJS famework. Obviously, I'd create a custom directive for every type. But how to tie in the control value reading and updating so that the two-way binding works flawlessly, and I could also make use of the special AngularJS form functionality (states, validation, etc)

Comment: Kinda confused. Control that does not interact with user in any way seems to be totally useless. You do not need to create hidden inputs for adding values to form.

Comment: Of course, it interacts. Every control dynamically creates some html+svg that user clicks to manipulate. Ok, perhaps I should not call it "pure JavaScript" then.

Comment: Ok, basically you just add ng-model and in directive require 'ngModel'. Then just play around with this controller. Not sure what exactly you need, to obtain some basic functionality you actually need nothing. http://plnkr.co/edit/BDyXOu2fNx5awbWuKTpM?p=preview